# Remove old entries from Visual Studio error list when starting new build.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

VS 2010 has irritating habit of keeping old errors (from last build) even after you start new build. 
  I see scenarios where this is nice, but I dont need it and it is irritating since it forces me to go through output window and search for errors in the current build.

BTW Im using VS for C++ development idk if that matters.

Comment: Does this happen after a Clean + Build (or a Rebuild) ?

Comment: hmmm, i had a failed build, then i did build solution and errors remained. now i did rebuild and errors are gone, maybe my VS setting are messed up, but still I would like it for a build also, because rebuild takes a lot of time so it is not a solution for me. :/

Comment: Odd, doesn't do it for me either.  In the output window there's a drop-down for "Show output from:" that's set to "Build" for me (in VS2012).  You might check yours... other than that I'm not aware of any configuration options for it...